# Question about forwarding ssl payload to upstream tcp server

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

These days, I am working on forwarding ssl payload to upstream tcp server using nginx, and the final nginx configure comes after a lot of experiment:

```
stream {
    map $ssl_server_name $stream_map {
        aby3_task_1 upstream_task_1;
        aby3_task_2 upstream_task_2;
    }

    upstream upstream_task_1 {
        server 127.0.0.1:1313;
    }

    upstream upstream_task_2 {
        server 127.0.0.1:1314;
    }

    server {
        listen 8185 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /home/ttt/nginx-cfg/cert/server1.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/ttt/nginx-cfg/cert/server1.key;
        proxy_pass $stream_map;
        ssl_preread off;
    }

    error_log /etc/nginx/logs/error.log debug;
}
```

The hardest problem during experiment is that nginx don't forward ssl payload into upstream tcp server according to server name, I worked on this problem for many days but got nothing. And yesterday my workmate removed `ssl_preread on` by accident then solves this problem. The default value of `ssl_preread` is `off`, so we realized that set `ssl_preread` to `off` would help us to solve the problem, this is the reason why `ssl_preread off` appears in the final nginx configure.
Why `ssl_preread on` has big impact to nginx's forward process? we collect some debug log when nginx forward runs well and runs bad, see below:

```
# This is the log when nginx can forward ssl payload to upstream tcp server.
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [info] 2952111#2952111: *1204 client 192.168.16.184:33868 connected to 0.0.0.0:8185
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 posix_memalign: 000055B8CEC6B700:256 @16
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 generic phase: 0
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 generic phase: 1
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 generic phase: 2
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 tcp_nodelay
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 SSL_do_handshake: -1
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 SSL_get_error: 2
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 epoll add event: fd:4 op:1 ev:80002001
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 event timer add: 4: 60000:8285386327
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 SSL handshake handler: 0
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 SSL_do_handshake: 1
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 SSL: TLSv1.2, cipher: "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH Au=RSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD"
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 event timer del: 4: 8285386327
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 generic phase: 2
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 ssl preread handler
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 proxy connection handler
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 malloc: 000055B8CEC92630:448
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 posix_memalign: 000055B8CEC8D1C0:256 @16
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 malloc: 000055B8CEC87C60:16384
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 post event 000055B8CECC87A0
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 stream map started
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 stream script var: "aby3_task_3"
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 stream map: "aby3_task_3" "upstream_task_3"
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 stream script var: "upstream_task_3"
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 get rr peer, try: 1
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 stream socket 18
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 epoll add connection: fd:18 ev:80002005
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 connect to 127.0.0.1:1315, fd:18 #1205
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 proxy connect: -2
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 event timer add: 18: 60000:8285386327
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 delete posted event 000055B8CECC87A0
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 SSL_read: -1
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 SSL_get_error: 2
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 event timer del: 18: 8285386327
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 stream proxy connect upstream
2023/01/28 14:25:17 [debug] 2952111#2952111: *1204 tcp_nodelay
```

```
# This is the log when nginx can't forward ssl payload to upstream tcp server.
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [info] 2950336#2950336: *1192 client 192.168.16.184:60998 connected to 0.0.0.0:8185
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [debug] 2950336#2950336: *1192 posix_memalign: 000055B8CEC6A530:256 @16
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [debug] 2950336#2950336: *1192 generic phase: 0
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [debug] 2950336#2950336: *1192 generic phase: 1
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [debug] 2950336#2950336: *1192 generic phase: 2
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [debug] 2950336#2950336: *1192 tcp_nodelay
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [debug] 2950336#2950336: *1192 SSL_do_handshake: -1
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [debug] 2950336#2950336: *1192 SSL_get_error: 2
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [debug] 2950336#2950336: *1192 epoll add event: fd:11 op:1 ev:80002001
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [debug] 2950336#2950336: *1192 event timer add: 11: 60000:8285270365
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [debug] 2950336#2950336: *1192 SSL handshake handler: 0
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [debug] 2950336#2950336: *1192 SSL_do_handshake: 1
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [debug] 2950336#2950336: *1192 SSL: TLSv1.2, cipher: "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH Au=RSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD"
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [debug] 2950336#2950336: *1192 SSL reused session
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [debug] 2950336#2950336: *1192 event timer del: 11: 8285270365
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [debug] 2950336#2950336: *1192 generic phase: 2
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [debug] 2950336#2950336: *1192 ssl preread handler
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [debug] 2950336#2950336: *1192 malloc: 000055B8CEC877F0:16384
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [debug] 2950336#2950336: *1192 SSL_read: -1
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [debug] 2950336#2950336: *1192 SSL_get_error: 2
2023/01/28 14:23:21 [debug] 2950336#2950336: *1192 event timer add: 11: 30000:8285240369
```

Compare the two log, we find that `proxy connection handler` occurs only in the case that nginx can forward ssl payload to upstream tcp server, so we assume that `ssl_preread on` will disable the forwarding, but why, can you tell me the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Today I notice a sentence in the introduction of nginx_stream_ssl_preread_module, the sentence is that `the ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module module (1.11.5) allows extracting information from the ClientHello message without terminating SSL/TLS`. I find very little detail hidden at the end of the sentence, it is `without terminating SSL/TLS`, then I know the answer to this problem.
SSL termination refers to the process of decrypting encrypted traffic before passing it along to a web server, and in our case，we want to decrypt encrypted traffic and pass it along to a TCP server, so what we want to Nginx do can also be called SSL termination. According to the introduction of ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module, we know that this module doesn't support our case, so we must set ssl_preread to off. Many days before, I try to use $ssl_preread_server_name in the map block and find the forward don't take effect after many experiments, today I know that the reason is the same as this question.